# Qgis action adding layers using relative paths

Tags: qgis, python, file-path, actions

in QGIS 2 windows
I have some index layers I use for loading raster and vector tiles through an Python action. Currently I am using absolute paths which works fine but I would like to set it up so other teams can use the tiles. I have been trying to get the path of the active layer (the index layer) and use that but had no luck.

I would also like to be able to load the new layers in a specific group to keep projects tidy - can this be done?

Comment: Relative to the project or current layer?

Answer (score 3):

If you want path to the current project you can do:

```
QgsProject.instance().fileName()
```

and the layer path using:

```
iface.activeLayer().source()
```

Getting the last folder:

```
>>> p = iface.activeLayer().source()
u'F:\\gis_data\\cadastre.shp'
>>> p = os.path.dirname(p)
u'F:/gis_data'
>>>folder = os.path.split(p)[-1]
u'gis_data'
```

Then you should use `os.path.join` to join on your new paths:

```
>>> newpath = os.path.join(folder, "myfolder", "myfile.shp")
u'gis_data\\myfolder\\myfile.shp'
```

To load a layer with the new path you would do something like this:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
p = os.path.dirname(iface.activeLayer().source())
folder = os.path.split(p)[-1]
newpath = os.path.join(folder, "myfolder", "myfile.shp")
iface.addVectorLayer(newpath, 'mylayer', 'ogr')
```

Just copy and paste this into a layer action and change the type to Python and it should work.

Comment: Thats great - now I need to figure out how to trim the filename off , some sort of a Substr operation

Comment: the os.path.dirname works now I need to figure out how to use the p in the action - which should be easy but still learning python                                                                                                                                            p = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().source()
p = qgis.utils.os.path.dirname(p)
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(" ADD PATH HERE \[% "TIle" %].asc")

Comment: See the edit I just made

Comment: That looks like it's gettting closer but the layer to load is a raster layer and the tile to load comes from the [% "TIle" %] attribute in the index layer. Thanks for all the help - I think I can crack it when I have a few mins

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
    from qgis.utils import iface
    p = os.path.dirname(iface.activeLayer().source())
    p = os.path.dirname(p)
    file = "asc/"+"[% "TIle" %]"+".asc"
    newpath = os.path.join(p,file)
    iface.addRasterLayer(newpath)
```